# Extracting rows based on more than two partial strings that must all be part of the string

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I want to extract rows that **must** contain two or more partial strings. For example, suppose I have the following data.table

```
df <- data.table(player = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'),
                 position = c('S Guard', 'P Guaaard', 'P Guard', 'S Forward',
                            'P Forward', 'Center', 'Center'),
                 points = c(28, 17, 19, 14, 23, 26, 5))
```

I know I can extract rows with either of the partial strings `Gua` or `rd` by using

```
df[grep("Gua|rd", df$position), ]
```

What if I want the the string to contain both `Gua` **and** `rd`? Tried

```
df[grep("Gua&rd", df$position), ]
```

both with and without space but doesn't work.

**EDIT WITH MORE INFO**

I'm actually dealing with relatively large datasets and I am using strings in one to extract data from another, something like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(player = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'),
                 position1 = c('S Guard', 'P Guard', 'P Guard', 'S Forward',
                            'P Forward', 'Center', 'Center'),
                 position2 = c('S Grd', 'P Guard', 'P rdGua', 'S Forward',
                             'P Forward', 'Center', 'Center'))

df2 <- data.table(player = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'),
                 points = c(28, 17, 19, 14, 23, 26, 5))

df2[df1[,3] %like% "Gua|rd",c(1,2)]
```

The order therefore shouldn't matter i.e **Guard** and **rdGua** should return true if using `&` in place of `|`.

Comment: I'm sure someone will give you a slick regex answer, but in the meantime, this will work: `df[grepl("Gua", df$position) & grepl("rd", df$position), ]`

Comment: I saw your proposed edit on my answer with the following comment *"List syntax used instead of dataframe syntax, as given in the question."*. I rejected that edit. To clarify: you can use list syntax on data.frames too and I personally prefer the list-syntax.

Answer (score 3):

If you replace `|` with `.*` you get the desired result. In stead of `grep` (or `grepl`), you can also use `like` from [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table).

`.*` indicates that every character is allowed in between "Gua" and "rd".

Two options:

```
# option 1
df[grep("Gua.*rd", position)]

# option 2
df[like(position, "Gua.*rd")]
```

both give:

> ```
>    player  position points
> 1:      A   S Guard     28
> 2:      B P Guaaard     17
> 3:      C   P Guard     19
> ```

Because you are using the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)-package, you don't need the `df$` part in between the square brackets.

---

In response to the extra information, you could achieve that with:

```
df2[df1[[3]] %like% "(Gua.*rd)|(rd.*Gua)"]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    player points
> 1:      B     17
> 2:      C     19
> ```

The `grep`/`grepl` alternatieve:

```
df2[grepl("(Gua.*rd)|(rd.*Gua)", df1[[3]])]
```

Comment: Maybe even `df[position %like% "Gua.*rd"]`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an overkill but if you don't know the order and want to avoid having multiple `grep()` calls you *could* do:

```
# Helper function
grepAnd <- function(vect, strings) {
  grep(
    do.call(sprintf, c(strrep('(?=.*%s)', length(strings)), as.list(strings))), 
    vect, 
    perl = TRUE
  )
}

inp <- c('Gua', 'rd')
df[grepAnd(position, inp)]

#    player  position points
# 1:      A   S Guard     28
# 2:      B P Guaaard     17
# 3:      C   P Guard     19

# Works even though the arguments are reversed
inp <- rev(inp)
df[grepAnd(position, inp)]
#    player  position points
# 1:      A   S Guard     28
# 2:      B P Guaaard     17
# 3:      C   P Guard     19


# Can search for more than two patterns
inp <- c(inp, 'P')
df[grepAnd(position, inp)]
#    player  position points
# 1:      B P Guaaard     17
# 2:      C   P Guard     19
```